# Pandas: using `map` for left merge returns NaN

Tags: python, pandas, merge, nan, type-conversion

I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
    X           Y           Order_  NEW_ID
0   484970.4517 408844.0920 95083   1320437
1   478512.3233 415791.5395 96478   1320727
2   504516.3032 452923.4420 105246  1321260
3   485147.0529 428172.1055 99633   1320979
```

And another one, `df2`:

```
    Order_  Loc
0   83158   239,211
1   83159   239,212
2   83160   239,213
3   83161   239,214
```

which I want to merge with the first so that the `Loc` column gets added with the correct values to `df1`. To do the merge, I use `map` to perform a left merge, first casting the `Loc` values as string:

```
df2['Loc'] = df2['Loc'].astype(str)
df1['Loc']=df1.Order_.map(df2.Loc)
```

The result is odd in that the `Loc` values appearing in `df1` are of the `NaN` type:

```
    X           Y           Order_  NEW_ID  Loc
0   484970.4517 408844.0920 95083   1320437 NaN
1   478512.3233 415791.5395 96478   1320727 NaN
2   504516.3032 452923.4420 105246  1321260 NaN
3   485147.0529 428172.1055 99633   1320979 NaN
```

whereas I expected them to be string and to appear in a `239,211` fashion (string that includes a comma). When investigating the dtype of `Loc` in `df2` I get:

```
Order_     int64
Loc       object
dtype: object
```

**My question:** How can I perform a change of type from object to string, so that I am able to effectively read the `Loc` values, and avoid their becoming `NaN`?

Comment: Unclear what you're expecting here, none of the posted Order_ values match between the two dfs

Comment: Yes, they don't in the example. The two dfs have thousands of lines.

Comment: `map` requires the index of the lookup df to match the column you're calling `map` on. So you need to call `set_index('Order_')` on `df2` first prior to calling `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need cast `Order_` to `int` if necessary for same `dtypes`:

```
df1['Order_'] = df1['Order_'].astype(int)
```

But maybe problem is you need map by `Series` or `dict`, so `Order_` has to be set to index:

```
d = df2.set_index('Order_')['Loc'].to_dict()
df1['Loc']= df1.Order_.map(d)
```

Sample:

```
print (df1)
             X            Y  Order_   NEW_ID
0  484970.4517  408844.0920   95083  1320437
1  478512.3233  415791.5395   96478  1320727
2  504516.3032  452923.4420  105246  1321260
3  485147.0529  428172.1055   99633  1320979

print (df2)
   Order_      Loc
0   95083  239,211 <-first value was changed for align
1   83159  239,212
2   83160  239,213
3   83161  239,214

#check if same dtypes
print (df1['Order_'].dtypes)
int64
print (df2['Order_'].dtypes)
int64


d = df2.set_index('Order_')['Loc'].to_dict()
print (d)
{83160: '239,213', 83161: '239,214', 95083: '239,211', 83159: '239,212'}

df1['Loc']= df1.Order_.map(d)
print (df1)
             X            Y  Order_   NEW_ID      Loc
0  484970.4517  408844.0920   95083  1320437  239,211
1  478512.3233  415791.5395   96478  1320727      NaN
2  504516.3032  452923.4420  105246  1321260      NaN
3  485147.0529  428172.1055   99633  1320979      NaN
```

Comment: But how can this affect the way in which `Loc` is added to `df1`?